# Adding a radio button to a Drupal View page

Tags: views, theming

Does anyone know how to 'inject' a radio button onto a Drupal View page?

I have an exposed filter that has nothing to do with a radio button but I want to add a radio button in front of the label in order to apply some additional AJAX to it.

Comment: Use HTML `<form>`, ex: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_radio

Comment: In front of Views label, or in front of exposed filter elements?

Comment: I have an exposed filter with a label and I'd like to add a radio button in front of the label (it would be completely disconnected from the view, just a totally new checkbox that I could apply some jquery to to hide/show the exposed filter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use HTML `<form>`, ex: [w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_radio](http://w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_radio)

To "inject" your code you could add a header text field to your view OR create a template file for your view.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I understand html. I guess I'll need to create a template file.